# How to read a txt file with php and replace certain variables?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to open, read, and render the contents of a .txt file using PHP.

I want to replace all the new lines, `\n`, with a `<br>`. I could echo it inside of a `<pre>` tag, but when I tried this method, the page was no longer responsive.

I also want to replace wherever it says `{ name }` or `$name` with a different variable, like how python fstrings work.

I currently have this:

```
echo file_get_contents("file.txt");
```

which will produce something that looks like this:

```
Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4 { Person1 }
```

How would I made the result look like this

```
Line1,
Line2,
Line3,
Line4 James
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, it is not possible to treat it as f-string because there is no builtin function to evaluate an f-string. However, you may format the content with `str.format` method. Like:

```
name = 'Person Name'
readFile = input('Txt File: ')
file = open(readFile, 'r')
content = file.read()
print(content.format(**locals()))
file.close()
```

```
Hello Person Name
line 2
```